# how to add value's to each other?

Tags: javascript

he i'm trying to study java-script, my idea was a input field for numbers. 
when a user fills a number my script should place it in a paragraph or a other text field. and when te user fills an other number in the first tekst field it counts the 2 value's together.

is something like this possible?

```js
var number = document.getElementById("getalInput");
var resultaat = document.getElementById("getalOutput")

number.onchange = function() {calculatie()};

function calculatie(){

  resultaat.innerHTML = number.value + " + " + "next value" + " + " + "and so on";
  resultaat.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" async></script>
  </head>

  <body>


    <input type="text" id="getalInput">
    <br>
    <p id="getalOutput"></p>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to add together using JS? Or concatenate strings?

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce a variable for the sum and use it for summing the value.

```js
var number = document.getElementById("getalInput"),
    resultaat = document.getElementById("getalOutput"),
    sum = 0;                     // new varaibale

number.onchange = calculatie;    // assign function directly for the event

function calculatie(){
  sum += +number.value || 0;     // get a number or zero for not number input
  resultaat.innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="getalInput"><br>
<p id="getalOutput"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```js
var number = document.getElementById("getalInput");
    var resultaat = document.getElementById("getalOutput")

    number.onchange = function() {calculatie()};

    function calculatie(){
      if(!resultaat.innerHTML.trim()){
        resultaat.innerHTML = number.value;
      }else{
        resultaat.innerHTML +=  " + " + number.value;
      }
      number.value = '';
      resultaat.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" async></script>
  </head>

  <body>


    <input type="text" id="getalInput">
    <br>
    <p id="getalOutput"></p>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there a possibility that you can explain how this works i cant understand it fully?